# Templating HTML programmatically

Tags: visual-studio, web

In order to simply create templates for HTML pages (no PHP, no ASPX etc), I need the ability to build up **HTML page-chunks** that I could then assemble to form a complete HTML page.

So that when I need adding a new menu item, I can re-assemble all the pages with the changed menu-chunk.

I tried W3C's Amaya, and got it fatal error on 1st attempt! Yes, it's W3C and it's a bug pot lol.

Komposer's outdated version had a templating model, but not in the new version.

Since I can't find any "honest" open source website editor to do that, I think I will try this as a solution:

Use c# of VB .NET to build a database out of all HTML chunks.
Create very simplistic web pages with chunk names as comments, like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">
    <title>A title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- menu_chunk12 -->
    <!-- body1_chunk -->
    <!-- footer3_chunk -->
</body>
</html>
```

When some chunk is edited, I just click a button and my little app will rebuild all the web pages and I'll re-publish them upload to the server.

What do you guru guys think about that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a terrible approach, but I would probably use some special notation in the comments like `<!-- #include(chunk_name) -->` so that these special comments are distinguished from regular comments.

You might also look at something like [htp](http://htp.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting idea, but in my opinion, if you want a little more extensibility, look into doing XSLT tranformations into HTML.  This would provide you a very homogeneous design, that would work on any platform serving HTML, and provide you with a complexity level you desire (simple or extreme).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I wrote a very simple but effective preprocesor for html that does this.

I used an extremely simple format where "@@" was used to introduce a command. The most useful command was "@@include " which caused another file's contents to be inserted in place of the include command.

Other useful commands would allow me to set variables, increment variables, and emit the value from a variable into the HTML output. These allow you to add things like a copyright date on all your pages and simply update it easily in a single @@included location.

It's a trivial program to write, and you have full power over the features.

I used this for about 10 years until I pretty much switched from html to php.